# CLion make install globally

Tags: cmake, clion, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I would like to build and install my project using CLion, however it must be installed globally (i.e. to `/usr/local/lib/cmake/`).

In bash I build with

`make -j$(nproc)
sudo make install`

and then run `sudo ldconfig` so that another app (gnuradio-companion) can find my project binaries.

When I run CLion as a regular user (non-root) and click *Run > Install*, I get 

`file INSTALL cannot set permissions on
  "/usr/local/lib/cmake/`

Is there any way to `sudo make install` and `sudo ldconfig` in CLion without starting CLion as root?